# add a custom ribbon tag in PowerPoint

Tags: c#, office-addins

I try to add a custom ribbon tab in PowerPoint using VSTO in C# (in the ribbon, I want to add a button)

I followed the [MSDN tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa942955.aspx) which is intended to Word but must be very similar.
I tested the same code for Word or Excel it works ad an "Addin" Tab is added to the ribbon. But with PowerPoint it doesn't.

My code. Here MyRibbon.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabAddIns">
        <group id="ContentGroup" label="Content">
          <button id="textButton" label="Insert Text"
               screentip="Text" onAction="OnTextButton"
               supertip="Inserts text at the cursor location."/>
          <button id="tableButton" label="Insert Table"
               screentip="Table" onAction="OnTableButton"
               supertip="Inserts a table at the cursor location."/>

        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

MyRibbon.cs:

```
public class MyRibbon : Office.IRibbonExtensibility
    {
        private Office.IRibbonUI ribbon;

        public MyRibbon()
        {
        }

        public string GetCustomUI(string ribbonID)
        {
            return GetResourceText("PowerPointAddIn2.MyRibbon.xml");
        }

        public void Ribbon_Load(Office.IRibbonUI ribbonUI)
        {
            this.ribbon = ribbonUI;
        }

        public void OnTextButton(Office.IRibbonControl control)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This text was added by the Ribbon.");
        }
```

ThisAddin.cs :

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e){}
private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e){}

protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
{
    return new MyRibbon();
}
```

Every files are under the same project.
Do you know what I have forgotten to add the addin Tab appear in PowerPoint ?

Comment: What's the name of your .xml file in your project?

Comment: the name of XML file is MyRibbon.xml

Comment: Is it directly under the project? Is the project name "PowerPointAddIn2"?

Comment: Yes. The project is PowerPointAddin2 and MyRibbon.cs and MyRibbon.xml are directly under it.

Comment: Do you believe there a problem in the architecture of my project ?

Comment: I'll give it a go building the project with your code tommorow. What version of PowerPoint are you using?

Comment: Thanks ! I am using Office 365

Comment: Is Office 2016 or 2013 installed on your machine?

Comment: It is 2016 version

Comment: Add a breakpoint on the  public string GetCustomUI(string ribbonID) and check that it really returns your xml file otherwise it looks OK to me

Comment: It does return my xml file

Answer (score 0):

your code looks find that your custom ribbon tab should be found within the PowerPoint menuebar under the add-in tab.
If you want to create your own tab, change your MyRibbon.xml code to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="MyRibbonTab" label="MyRibbon">
        <!-- idMso="TabAddIns" -->
        <group id="ContentGroup" label="Content">
          <button id="textButton" label="Insert Text"
               screentip="Text" onAction="OnTextButton"
               supertip="Inserts text at the cursor location."/>
          <button id="tableButton" label="Insert Table"
               screentip="Table" onAction="OnTableButton"
               supertip="Inserts a table at the cursor location."/>

        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

I hope this helps you or others.
If you want to learn more see [Microsoft Docs - Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using Ribbon XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-ribbon-xml?view=vs-2019)